# Passing Javascript variables to CakePdf

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, pdf

I need to pass a variable (actually an extensive amount of HTML, dynamically generated via JavaScript) to the 'view' controller that will output a PDF (using the CakePdf plugin / wkHtmlToPdf).

I have tried via Ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo $this->webroot . $this->params["controller"]; ?>/view/"+$id+".pdf",
       data: {id: $id, matrix: $matrix.html()},
       success: function(data){
        console.log(data);      
       }
     });
```

And it does seem to return `data` containing the PDF stream, however I was unable to send it to browser. (This is done by the plugin so I can't echo it - the plugin probably attempts to do that already, but as the request is done in the background it does not work).

I have also tried using the postLink method to generate the button.

```
<li><?php  echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Button'), array('action' => 'view', $project['Project']['id'].'.pdf'), null); ?> </li>
```

It does work, in terms of generating the PDF. But I do not know how to pass the JavaScript variable ($matrix) in this case.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you calrify your question ! what do you want to achieve exactly ??

Comment: Basically I need to post some lengthy data to my controller that will handle the data and display a PDF using the CakePdf plugin. When I tried using an asynchronous request it was not "echoing" properly. And when I tried using the `postLink` method of the Form component to generate the links I was not being able to pass my "JavaScript variables" to my controller. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is the most elegant answer (and most probably not), but I was able to work around the issue by making use of a hidden form to submit my data.

```
    <form action="projects/view/" name="frmPrint" id="frmPrint" style="display:none;" method="post">
                <input id="printData" type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    </form>
    <a id="printMatrix">Print</a></li>
```

Using JavaScript (jQuery) I was then changing the printData on the go before submitting the form.

```
function printMatrix() {
    var $matrix = $('#matrix'); // the element to be sent via post
    $('#printData').val( $matrix[0].innerHTML ); // updating the hidden input       
    $('#frmPrint').submit(); // submitting the form
}
```

There is a binding event on the click trigger of the `<a>` tag:

```
$(document).on('click', '#printMatrix', function(event){ printMatrix(); });
```